# Chamada do request laravel

Tags: laravel

Bom dia!

Estou programando um sistema e não consegui achar uma resposta para minha dúvida!

Eu tenho um campo (input), chamado `nome_atendimento`. Preciso chamar esse input diretamente no meu Controller. Existe alguma diferença em chamar:  `$request->nome_atendimento`
e `$request->input('nome_atendimento')` ? O mesmo se aplica para arquivo, posso chamar diretamente `$request->nome_arquivo` ou devo chamar `$request->file('nome_arquivo')` ?

Answer (score -2):

Olá

Pelo que vi, não há diferenças impactantes em usos normais, só que com o input('') você consegue acessar inputs que vierem em array utilizando o ponto

exemplo:

```
<input name="usuario[0][name]" value="Airton" />
```

você conseguiria acessar com o input utilizando dessa forma:

```
$request->input('usuario.0.name')
```

Fonte:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186169/laravel-request-input-or-get